# How to arrange groups of rows.in alternating order, in T-SQL query output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I need some one to give me an idea of how to arrange thes rows.

I want the rows to follow this pattern:

1. TRNS
2. SPL
3. ENDTRNS

This is what I have

```
+-------+------------+----------+------------+--------+
|  Id   | Trans Type | Document |    Date    | Amount |
+-------+------------+----------+------------+--------+
| 14184 | ENDTRNS    | NULL     | NULL       | NULL   |
| 14184 | ENDTRNS    | NULL     | NULL       | NULL   |
| 14184 | ENDTRNS    | NULL     | NULL       | NULL   |
| 14184 | ENDTRNS    | NULL     | NULL       | NULL   |
| 14184 | SPL        | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | -745   |
| 14184 | SPL        | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | -800   |
| 14184 | SPL        | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | -860   |
| 14184 | SPL        | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | -1170  |
| 14184 | TRNS       | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | 745    |
| 14184 | TRNS       | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | 800    |
| 14184 | TRNS       | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | 860    |
| 14184 | TRNS       | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | 1170   |
+-------+------------+----------+------------+--------+
```

I am trying to get the following as the final result

```
+-------+------------+----------+------------+--------+
|  Id   | Trans Type | Document |    Date    | Amount |
+-------+------------+----------+------------+--------+
| 14184 | TRNS       | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | 1170   |
| 14184 | SPL        | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | -1170  |
| 14184 | ENDTRNS    | NULL     | NULL       | NULL   |
| 14184 | TRNS       | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | 860    |
| 14184 | SPL        | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | -860   |
| 14184 | ENDTRNS    | NULL     | NULL       | NULL   |
| 14184 | TRNS       | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | 800    |
| 14184 | SPL        | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | -800   |
| 14184 | ENDTRNS    | NULL     | NULL       | NULL   |
| 14184 | TRNS       | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | 745    |
| 14184 | SPL        | INVOICE  | 01/07/1990 | -745   |
| 14184 | ENDTRNS    | NULL     | NULL       | NULL   |
+-------+------------+----------+------------+--------+
```

I think am close, this is what I am working on

```
;WITH CTE_Sample AS 
(
    SELECT 
        '14184' AS [Id],
        'ENDTRNS' AS [Trans Type],
        'NULL' AS [Document],
        'NULL' AS [Date],
        'NULL' AS [Amount]
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT 
        '14184' AS [Id],
        'ENDTRNS' AS [Trans Type],
        'NULL' AS [Document],
        'NULL' AS [Date],
        'NULL' AS [Amount]
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT 
        '14184' AS [Id],
        'ENDTRNS' AS [Trans Type],
        'NULL' AS [Document],
        'NULL' AS [Date], 
        'NULL' AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'ENDTRNS' AS [Trans Type],'NULL' AS [Document],'NULL' AS [Date],'NULL' AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'SPL' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],'-745' AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'SPL' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],'-800' AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'SPL' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],'-860' AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'SPL' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],'-1170' AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'TRNS' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],'745' AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'TRNS' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],'800' AS [Amount]
UNION ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'TRNS' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],'860' AS [Amount]
UNION ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'TRNS' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],'1170' AS [Amount]
)
SELECT 
    ID, [Trans Type], Document, [Date], Amount,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, [Trans Type] ORDER BY Amount ASC) AS rownum
FROM 
    CTE_Sample
ORDER BY 
    ROWNUM
```

I can't figure out how to get `ENDTRNS` at the end of each group of rows from top to bottom

Comment: I don't think there is a way -- unless they are each a different ID -- right now the only way to know which go together is by the amount.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want an id by transaction once you have that you can do this:

```
SELECT ID,[Trans Type],Document,[Date],Amount 
FROM CTE_Sample
ORDER BY ID_BY_TRANSACTION, CASE [Trans Type] 
                             WHEN 'TRNS' THEN 1 
                             WHEN 'SPL' THEN 2
                             WHEN 'ENDTRNS' THEN 3 END
```

There must be a transaction id somewhere in your system.

Comment: There is no ID_BY_TRANSACTION

Answer (score 0):

You had amount as text (varchar).  That messes up sort

```
SELECT ID, [Trans Type], Document,[Date], Amount 
  , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID, [Trans Type] 
                       ORDER BY abs(isnull(Amount, '0')) desc ) AS rownum
FROM CTE_Sample
ORDER BY ROWNUM, [Trans Type] desc
```

Comment: @KamilG. Did you test?

Comment: @KamilG. Amount is a string so is sorts incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
;WITH CTE_Sample AS 
(
    SELECT 
        '14184' AS [Id],
        'ENDTRNS' AS [Trans Type],
        'NULL' AS [Document],
        'NULL' AS [Date],
        NULL AS [Amount]
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT 
        '14184' AS [Id],
        'ENDTRNS' AS [Trans Type],
        'NULL' AS [Document],
        'NULL' AS [Date],
        NULL AS [Amount]
    UNION  ALL
    SELECT 
        '14184' AS [Id],
        'ENDTRNS' AS [Trans Type],
        'NULL' AS [Document],
        'NULL' AS [Date], 
        NULL AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'ENDTRNS' AS [Trans Type],'NULL' AS [Document],'NULL' AS [Date],NULL AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'SPL' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],-745 AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'SPL' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],-800 AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'SPL' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],-860 AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'SPL' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],-1170 AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'TRNS' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],745 AS [Amount]
UNION  ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'TRNS' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],800 AS [Amount]
UNION ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'TRNS' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],860 AS [Amount]
UNION ALL
SELECT '14184' AS [Id],'TRNS' AS [Trans Type],'INVOICE' AS [Document],'01/07/1990' AS [Date],1170 AS [Amount]
)
SELECT ID,[Trans Type],Document,[Date],Amount 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,[Trans Type] ORDER BY abs(Amount) desc) AS rownum
FROM CTE_Sample
ORDER BY rownum ,CASE [Trans Type] 
                             WHEN 'TRNS' THEN 1 
                             WHEN 'SPL' THEN 2
                             WHEN 'ENDTRNS' THEN 3 END
```

Answer (score -1):

the query i posted is part of a larger one.for this particular sample  i have used

```
SELECT ID,[Trans Type],Document,[Date],Amount 
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID,[Trans Type] ORDER BY Amount  asc ) AS rownum
FROM CTE_Sample
ORDER BY rownum,CASE [Trans Type] 
                             WHEN 'TRNS' THEN 1 
                             WHEN 'SPL' THEN 2
                             WHEN 'ENDTRNS' THEN 3 END
```

but i need to test it further to prevent it failing in future.

Comment: You can't sort text stored in `Amount` and think that it behaves the same as sorting integers.

Comment: This does not produce the posted desired results